# Google Cloud Platform: OAuth rate limits

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have app on Google Cloud Platform and r**ecently passed the verification process**. However, in the **OAuth consent screen** I can see **OAuth rate limits** which is set to 100.

[image]

I don't understand why it is present there as the app is already verified. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the wording is a bit misleading there.
As long as your app is verified and not requesting for unverified sensitive scopes you should be fine and new users shouldn't be counted towards this cap.
I think this bar stays there even after successful verification because it is cumulative and if in future  your app will request access to another sensitive scope it will continue to count until your app again verified.
[Here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865) it should be explained better.

Answer (score 1):

I think OAuth rate limit is for, how many Auth requests your account is allowed to handle.

Thank you for reading!!

Comment: It says: number of users who can grant permission to sensitive scopes. My question is why it is present there as my app is verified.